# Google Analytics Query for R, content drilldown

Tags: r, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-filters

I am trying to export Google Analytics data into R in order to build a report and do some other data mining related tasks with the data. I am using the RGoogleAnalytics package to do so. I have the connection working, but am having trouble specifying the correct query in order to obtain the right information.

I am trying to obtain information from a specific page that I would reach by going to the content drilldown section in google analytics, and searching for that specific page. I also would like to use a filtered view, to filter out ISP's that are from my work place. There are several websites under a particular view. To reach the specific page, I use the content drill down in Google Analytics. I am trying to build a query that pulls this information automatically. I have tried the following in regards to getting the correct query.

```
ValidateToken(token1)

query.list1 <- Init(start.date = "2016-10-28", end.date = "2016-12-05",
           dimensions = "ga:date", metrics = "ga:uniquepageviews",
           filters = "ga:pagePathLevel1                
           ==/ed######.edu/;ga:pagePathLevel2==/content/",   
           table.id = "ga:##### ")
           sort = "ga:date"
ga.query <- QueryBuilder(query.list1)
ga.data <- GetReportData(ga.query, token1)
```

This does not throw in error in R, but does not seem to be returning any metrics(it returns all zeros, for unique pageviews, when there are results) as shown below.

```
   **date**   **uniquepageviews**
```

1    20161028               0

2    20161029               0

3    20161030               0

4    20161031               0

In the above, I tried to use the filter to get the correct page. Is this correct? If so, what should I put into the filter so that it only returns metrics for a specific page in a given view? Also, is there a way to select for a given prebuilt view? Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Query seems to be correct, what happens when you do not specify any filter? Does it return non-zero unique pageviews?

Comment: Dikesh, when removing the filter, it gives nonzero numbers of unique page views, but I had assumed this perhaps was a combination of several of the websites, although the numbers look a bit lower than I would expect when including all of the websites. Just as a quick check, the table id specifies the overall user account, not a specific view or website, correct?

Comment: No, table.id is Google Analytics profile also called as view.

Comment: Alright, I might play around with views then and see if I can create a view with a filter that includes just the website of interest, then use that table id/view id for the query. Thanks,

Comment: I would first try the query without filters to check the rest of the query is ok, and then rather than using pagePathLevel1;pagePathLevel2 just use ga:pagePath

Comment: Thanks, I did that, and it is returning results. I played around with it, and seem to be getting nonzero returns when using a regex expression for a filter. So, for filter, I typed filters = "ga:landingPagePath=~^ed#####", and that is giving results, although the returns differ numerically from another the google analytics output the report, so I still need to figure out why that is occurring.

Comment: You need to collapse down to the root folder in the path (e.g., /domains, /domains/view/180000, /domains/view/120000, etc would be binned into /domains)